# Zoom image in Webview

Tags: android, image, webview, zooming

I have an image and other elements (div, titles etc.) in my webview and i need only the image to zoom on click, like picture in gallery. Something like in this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/). but in webview. I only found, how to zoom whole webview.

Comment: You can use Java Script or JQuery for that and enable JavaScript property for WebView.

Comment: How can you get image in webview? where is the source of Image?

Comment: source of image is in assets/images in my case

Answer (score 6):

You can use this.

```
 webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/images/yourimage.png");
 webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);  
 webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, i tried this and it is not what i am looking for...the text around image disappeared and zooming is very user unfriedly imho. I can't divide my actual webview to two different webviews - one with image and second with text, because i need wrap text around image...

Comment: Want to zoom your image on Touch on it in webview?